# Are files in memory the same size as they are in the file system?

Tags: java, file, memory, centos, filesystems

I've been working with large log files (~100 MB) in Java and noticed that `gzip` can compress them to around ~3MB, making them 35x smaller.

So I wonder: do modern OSes compress files before loading them into memory? It seems silly to use 100 MB of RAM to hold a file that really only has 3 MB of information.

Or is it the opposite? Does the process of reading a file (and dealing with encodings and whatnot) mean that a file which takes up 100MB on disk is actually bigger than 100MB in memory?

*bonus points: Any recommendations for preprocessing I could do to my files before loading them in order to reduce my `JVM`'s memory usage? (The files have the same format as `Apache` server logs.)

Comment: If you held the compressed data in memory, you would have to perform decompression anytime you wanted to use that data. Either that, or change your code to work with compressed data, which seems extremely overwhelming and un-necessary. Either way, if you wanna use the data, it would have to be decompressed into it's original form at some point, unless you don't plan on manipulating/accessing parts of that data. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do modern OSes compress files before loading them into memory? It seems silly to use 100 MB of RAM to hold a file that really only has 3 MB of information.

This would depend on the application involved. Some applications may compress data held in memory, others may not.

> Or is it the opposite? Does the process of reading a file (and dealing with encodings and whatnot) mean that a file which takes up 100MB on disk is actually bigger than 100MB in memory?

Again, depends entirely on the application.

> *bonus points: Any recommendations for preprocessing I could do to my files before loading them in order to reduce my JVM's memory usage? (The files have the same format as Apache server logs.)

Don't load any data into memory that you do not need for processing or display. Anything that is simply required for producing an average or sum can be loaded temporarily and added into the running total, and can then be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You get only what you ask for. If you compress it, it will be compressed.
Most of the time there will be a slight difference between the size in memory and the size on the disk. But that is only due to the fact that unit of storage on the disk (sector) is larger. Even for 1 byte file you most of the time use more than that on the disk because the OS reserve a sector for that and it will depend on OSes, you will mostly find sector of 512, 2048 or 4096 bytes.